# Can I use IE edge with old versions of ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs, cross-browser, extjs3, x-ua-compatible

I want to use

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Will it cause any problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly suggest you to **not** use old versions of JavaScript libraries. They usually have bugs that have been fixed in newer versions.

Chances are good that a very new browser version (especially of IE) results in some issues that are usually quickly fixed in a new version of the library, but if you stay with an ancient version.. well, your scripts might break!

Comment: The old versions of JavaScript libraries are used by a very huge web application (that we are developing) and it is not cost effective to switch to newer versions right now. Though I want to rewrite it in a newer versions, I'm just an employee.